# SQL Datatype to use when inserting money

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL database and I have to insert a monetary value(salary) as part of a row. For some strange reason the money command isnt working, is there any alternates that would work with this?

Data input format: £00,000.000

```
CREATE TABLE staff
                   (staffno CHAR(6) NOT NULL
                    , staffsurname VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
                    , staffforename VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
                    , salary MONEY NOT NULL
                    , PRIMARY KEY (staffno)
                   );
```

Comment: Oracle, my apologies - fixed the tag.

Comment: Oracle recommends the use of `varchar2()` rather than `varchar()` for strings, as a note.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at this line

```
salary MONEY NOT NULL
```

There is no existing money datatype.

If you are looking for something similar to `SQL-Server` small money type, you want to use a `Number(10,4)` and then format the number.

You can format the number using `to_char` function

```
select to_char(yourColumn, '$99,999.99') from yourTable where someCondition
```

Comment: There is no front-end to this application, just structuring the database (I am a student so its just practicing using oracles iacademy) so I can't parse the string.

Comment: For example if my input were: £45,000.00. Would it work using VARCHAR(7,2)?

Comment: @user3686991 varchar does not have decimal type, it is only characters.

Comment: You could just store it as `varchar(15)` if you want to store data with sign and comma etc. Note that 15 may not be the correct length, change it to whatever limit you want to allow.

Comment: I think using a `VARCHAR` (actually `VARCHAR2` since it's Oracle) is a Bad Idea. It would pretty much rule out doing range queries on that column.

Answer (score 7):

The "strange" reason is simple: [There is no MONEY data type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT012).

The data type most appropriate for monetary values would be [`NUMBER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT313) (using an appropriate *scale*). Since it is a *decimal* floating-point type, it is better suited for monetary values than the *binary* floating-point types `BINARY_FLOAT` and `BINARY_DOUBLE`.

Note, though, that you will still need to *parse* the input string `£00,000.000` in your front end and send it *as a numeric value* to the back end.

Comment: Okay and what would be the correct format for inserting a monetary value of £00,000.00?

Comment: a monetary value of zero is simply `0`.