# SQL: Missing Parenthesis

Tags: sql, database, oracle, parentheses, banking

I have tried editing the command and looking at other questions in order to answer this question, but I still get the dreaded

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.

Here is my code. Is there any key word that I may need to drop here? Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE Loan
(
    LoanID       INT IDENTITY ( 1, 1 ) UNIQUE,
    BranchID     INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Branch(BranchID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    LoanNumber   CHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    LoanType     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Amount       MONEY NOT NULL,
    ModifiedDate DATETIME DEFAULT (getdate()),

    PRIMARY KEY ( LoanID )
);
```

Comment: Several parts of that are not valid Oracle syntax. Have you copied it from another DBMS? And which version of Oracle are you trying to run it against?

Comment: I am running it on the current Oracle Application Express website. I believe that the code I have my have outdated syntax. How would I have to account for the IDENTITY keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following ddl is syntactically correct. Of course, you have to check whether that statement really produces what you want ( in particular the `IDENTITY` keyword in your original statement is not accounted for ):

```
CREATE TABLE Loan
(
      LoanID       INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , BranchID     INTEGER NOT NULL               CONSTRAINT tl_fk_branchid  REFERENCES Branch(BranchID) ON DELETE CASCADE
    , LoanNumber   CHAR(20) NOT NULL              CONSTRAINT tl_u_loannumber UNIQUE 
                       -- right padded to length of 20 with blanks 
    , LoanType     VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
    , Amount       Number(*,4) NOT NULL     
                       -- cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29014422, changed per @BobJarvis' comment
    , ModifiedDate DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
);
```

The syntax deviations are as follows:

- `IDENTITY`keyword
- inline constraint specification
- datatype to represent date and time
- datatype for string content
- stand-in for money datatype
- current datetime

Comment: In the declaration for AMOUNT a precision of 10 seems rather low for a monetary value as this only allows for six digits to the left of the decimal point. The precision can be left off by specifying `*` which serves as a fill-in for the maximum possible precision of 38, and thus the definition would be `Amount NUMBER(*,4)`.

Comment: @BobJarvis You have a point here - I took the recommendation from the referenced SO answer trusting the author in that the suggested dimension suits loan applications. I have adjusted the solution according to your hint.