# What am I doing wrong with my Number precision and scale?

Tags: sql, oracle, precision

I'm trying to insert the following statement in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
INSERT INTO ACC
VALUES (1245890, 234.50, 'Broomhill', '15-NOV-2003', 100.00);
```

The statement inserts well enough without an error, but I noticed when looking at the data view that the row displays the 2nd and 4th values with one less decimal point.

(E.g 234.5 and 100.0 when it's supposed to be 234.50 and 100.00)

I tried to increase the precision and scale in my table create code to allow it to display properly.

```
CREATE TABLE ACC
(
"ACCNO" NUMBER(7),
"BALANCE" NUMBER(5,2),
"BRANCH" VARCHAR(15),
"OPENED" DATE,
"BONUS" NUMBER(5,2)
);
```

I changed the BALANCE and BONUS datatypes slightly

```
CREATE TABLE ACC
(
"ACCNO" NUMBER(7),
"BALANCE" NUMBER(5,3)
"BRANCH" VARCHAR(15),
"OPENED" DATE,
"BONUS" NUMBER(5,3)
);
```

but instead I get an error saying that:

```
Error starting at line : 94 in command -
INSERT INTO ACC
VALUES (1245890, 234.50, 'Broomhill', '15-NOV-2003', 100.00)
Error report -
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```

What am I doing wrong with my code? How can I write it so it'll display my values properly?

Comment: The standard answer is that this is a formatting issue that the code _accessing_ your data should be dealing with. What's stored is the necessary information for you to format the data any way you wish.

Comment: Does this number represent money? If so, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014283/sql-datatype-to-use-when-inserting-money

Comment: By the way, date literals should be written like `date '2003-11-03'`.

Answer (score 3):

`NUMBER(5, 3)` is a number that has five digits in it, with three to the right of the decimal -- so two are to the left.  The value "100.00" has three to the left, so it doesn't fit.

You seem to want:  `NUMBER(6, 3)`.

Comment: It displays 100.00 properly, but 234.50 is still displaying as 234.5

Comment: @HenryGreen That missing zero is not _significant_, meaning we could really write any number of zeroes to the right of the `.5` and it wouldn't change the logical meaning of the number.  You can handle this using a formatting function in Oracle, or better yet handle it in your presentation layer.

Comment: But there's a key difference between 234.50 and 234.5. That extra 0 is needed to highlight that, I'm not sure how to use the formatting function to display that.

Comment: There is no difference [arithmetically](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=234.50+-+234.5). Gordon has answered the ORA-01438 question - display formatting is a separate issue.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers are correctly stored into a table, but they aren't displayed the way you want so you have to use a proper format mask. Here's an example:

```
SQL> select to_char(234.50, '990D00') val_1,
  2         to_char(100, '990D00') val_2
  3  from dual;

VAL_1   VAL_2
------- -------
 234,50  100,00

SQL>
```

This is SQL*Plus; you can set it in other (Oracle) tools, such as Forms, Reports, Apex, etc., usually in item's Property Palette window.

Have a look at Format models, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm